# How to include the control options of a component inside a stories.mdx file?

Tags: javascript, storybook, stenciljs

I have a `..stories.mdx` file which is shown in Storybook. In it, I have this:

```
import { Meta, Description } from '@storybook/addon-docs';
import {
  Story,
  Source,
  ArgsTable,
  Canvas,
} from '@storybook/addon-docs';
import dedent from 'ts-dedent';

import text_en from './About_en.md';


<Meta title="Icons" parameters={{ previewTabs: { canvas: { hidden: true }, 'storybook/docs/panel': { hidden: true }, 'usage-tab/panel': { hidden: true } } }} />


<Description markdown={text_en} />

<Canvas columns={2} withSource="open" >
  <Story id="components-icon--default"></Story>
</Canvas>

<ArgsTable id="components-icon--default" />

<ifx-icons-preview />
```

Inside the canvas, I am displaying the Icon component, and below the Canvas, I am displaying the  component. But my `Icon` component has control options which are not being shown here.

Where control options should be shown, there is just a text saying: `Args unsupported`.

I have tried doing this:

```
<ArgsTable story="." />
```

but it still doesn't work. Instead of `Args unsupported`, it says `Nothing found`.

Inside my `Icon.stories.ts` file, my args look like this:

```
export default {
  title: 'Components/Icon',
  args: {
    icon: "c-check-16"
  }
}
```

I have tried including argTypes, like this:

```
  argTypes: {
    icon: { control: 'text' },
  },
```

but nothing changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using SB v7? ArgTables is deprecated in this version, use <Controls />